# Conditional formatting for cell that contain text (not number)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to apply conditional formatting to highlight cell that contain text (not number), is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your conditional formatting formula, you can use: `=isnumber(0+A1)` assuming `A1` is your cell that you are testing.

The `0+` bit will attempt to add 0 to the contents of A1, which will convert the contents to a number, even if it's a number stored as text.

Answer (score 4):

You might use a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=ISTEXT(A1)
```

where the cell is non numeric or contains text.

Answer (score 0):

Use Format Cell Value NOT BETWEEN (Any number range). Excel will format all the text cells as they're not numbers so do not fall into the value range.