# Excel conditional formatting to identify values that are time values not numeric values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need to use conditional formatting to either: -

1. Identify time values in a sheet which should only contain numeric values or
2. Identify any cells that aren't numeric values (not 100% on this as time values possibly stored in similar to numeric values).

I'm looking around and experimenting all morning but I can't nail it down.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Edit: For reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867544/conditional-formatting-for-cell-that-contain-text-not-number) answer does not answer my question, as I'm trying to identify cells that contain time values, rather than simple numeric values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional formatting for cell that contain text (not number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867544/conditional-formatting-for-cell-that-contain-text-not-number)

Comment: I've just removed the edit to my post. I thought that answer did help, but the =isnumber(0+A1) seems to be highlighting all of my cells for some reason. I think the values are stored as general in the sheet, but most are going through to my formulas as numbers, but time values aren't coming through properly.

Comment: Times and dates in excel are stored as numbers, so its not easy to differentiate between true numbers and numbers that are actually time. The following formula will identify if a value is a time or not based on the format, but ive not been able to get it working in a conditional format  =IF(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(G3,"hh:mm:ss"))=G3, "Time Entry", "Not a Time Entry")

Comment: Thanks, @A.Steer. That has identified one cell in question as a time value. Do you know if there's a way I can run the formula over multiple cells in a row at the same time i.e. if any of these contain a time value, return yes or something. I could then conditionally format that control column cell to highlight red any rows that say Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following formula as a conditional formatting rule it will then highlight the cells that are time values.

```
=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(C3,"hh:mm:ss"))
```

In testing I have had to create the rule on a cell that is already a number value and then apply it to every other cell as it was changing the format of time cells to their underlying number if done otherwise.

Create a new conditional formatting rule for cell C3 with the above formula as the rule.

[image: Conditional Format rule]

Then when applied, right click the cell and copy, then select the range of cells you want to apply the format to and select Paste Special - formats.

This should then hightlight any value that has a time format

Comment: Thanks @A.Steer. I will try that tomorrow and will revert. Much appreciated

Comment: That's not working, it's highlighting cells that are numbers red too. Apologies for the delay getting back I'm on holidays. I will have a more detailed look next week. Thanks for your help